# create double view with same url alias for different theme

Tags: views

In my drupal. I created a two theme one for desktop and another for mobile using [Mobile switch](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_switch) I change the theme. Now I Created a View as a page for desktop with alias "xxx/yyy" and for mobile also I created a view as a page with same alias "xxx/yyy"(some modification Done). While switching the theme from desktop to mobile, the desktop view is appear. How to differentiate?

Comment: Do you prefer developing solution or solution that can do it in views?

Comment: developing solution

Answer (score 3):

ok

create a menu with hook_menu 
then with checking condition you want load your views in callback of your menu

Something like below

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['myurl'] = array(
    'title' => 'title',
    'page callback' => 'myfunction_callbackfuction',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

function myfunction_callbackfuction() {
  $view = views_get_view('view_name');
if($mycondtion)
  $view->set_display('page1');
else 
  $view->set_display('page2');

  $view->pre_execute();
  $view->execute();
  print $view->render();
}
```

Comment: is it any hook function to disable the particular view.

Comment: @vinox you can create 2 master views without any page or block

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this by using

```
$view_name = 'my_views_name';
$display_id = 'my_views_display_id';
print views_embed_view($view_name , $display_id);
```